# Start storyboard at the same time with one buttonclick in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I'm trying to make a flip animation, and have one that flips when it's a loaded RoutedEvent, but I want it to flip when the RoutedEvent is Button.Click. This is my code so far:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="AnimatedScaleTransform" ScaleX="-1" />
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="gurbe1.jpg"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" Completed="Storyboard1_Completed">
                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:1"  Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="AnimatedScaleTransform2" ScaleX="0" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="gurbe2.jpg"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard2">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:2.3" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>



</Grid>
```

So is there a way to start the storyboards with just one click?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: So the animation is supposed to look like it's flipping, from one image to the other. So I made two buttons, each with their own image. I want the first button to flip instantly when it's clicked and want the other button to flip a bit later. I did this by adding the Begintime. Now my problem is, The RoutedEvent of the second button is loaded, but I want it to start when the first animation is done, not just after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

So i think i got it:

**XAML**

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <BeginStoryboard x:Key="begin">
        <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:1"  Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
    <BeginStoryboard x:Key="twa">
        <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard2">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:2.3" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</Window.Resources>



<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Width="100" Click="button1_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="AnimatedScaleTransform" ScaleX="-1" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="gurbe1.jpg"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Click="button1_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="AnimatedScaleTransform2" ScaleX="0" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="gurbe2.jpg"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
        private void Clicked_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BeginStoryboard sb = this.FindResource("begin2") as BeginStoryboard;
        sb.Storyboard.Begin();
    }
```